# Is there a way to make Chaotic Neutral Anti-Paladin?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, antipaladin

There are anti-paladins templates such as  Paladin of Tyranny requires Lawful Evil and Paladin of Slaughter requires Chaotic Evil. Are there any Chaotic Neutral aligned anti-paladin type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is!

*Dragon* vol. 310 has the anarch, a CN paladin, in the article “Champions of the Divine” starting on page 46. They get a different skill list, instances of good are replaced with chaos and evil with law, and they get different ribbons¹ from the paladin. Turn undead becomes turn construct, which is super-weird. The spell list is different, which doesn’t really matter from a core perspective (since both the anarch and the core paladin spell lists are poor), but you’ll have to discuss with your DM which non-core spells should go on the anarch list and/or which non-core paladin spells should be adapted for anarchs.

1. <sub>“Ribbons” are minor class features that are more about fluff than anything. In this case, lay on hands, divine health, and *remove disease*, which are replaced with destructive strike, slippery mind, and *dispel law*, respectively.</sub>

Comment: Is the name of the book Dragon Compendium Volume 1?

Comment: @UniQuadrion No, sorry, it’s not in a book—it’s in an issue of _Dragon_ magazine, specifically volume 310. _Dragon_ magazine was/is the official D&D magazine, though at the time it was published by Paizo (who now do Pathfinder) under license from Wizards of the Coast. _Dragon Compendium_ (there was only ever one volume but I guess they were optimistic) includes a bunch of stuff from various _Dragon_ magazine issues, but it doesn’t include the anarch, sad to say. Anyway, even if you can’t find the magazine, the fact that it officially existed may help make the case for your own adaptation.

Comment: I see. Sadly if it is not in any of the books, my DM wont accept it unless I can get a hold of the official magazine.

Comment: @UniQuadrion Well, #310 is one of the best—the whole issue was dedicated to class variants like this, for all the classes. _Really_ useful for bringing various character ideas to life. So it might be worth tracking that one down in particular.

Comment: Turn Construct actually makes some sense because Constructs are somewhat associated with Law (Mechanus in Great Wheel for instance).

Comment: @Cubic I’m aware of the association, but it’s weak. Mechanus has constructs, but so does every place else. The plane itself is a machine, but there is a distinction between machine and construct there. Modrons are machine-like, but _not_ constructs. And ultimately the association of robots with Law is due to then following orders, moving predictably, but those features only describe mindless constructs—and equally-well describe mindless undead. Turn construct makes way less sense than it might seem—I didn’t want to get into it in the answer but I wanted a nod to the problems.